# Making parent div resize to 100% of child divs with an absolute centered div

Tags: html, css, layout

I need your help. Does anyone know a way of making a Parent's Div height size relative to its child divs.

If I define an auto height to the DIV #layout then the div resizes to 100% of my page window. However, If I define the height on the #layout div then I need to account for every pixel used on the screen in order to keep my border nice and clean around the layout div. How can I make the height on the #layout div box re-size to its contents?

Below is picture of the problem. As you can see the #box6 breaks the #layout div.

Maybe I am missing something that I have overlooked but I am not sure where to begin.
[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS in question:

```css
* {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: rgb(187, 195, 203);
}
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#layout {
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(112, 112, 112);
}
#box1 {
  background: rgb(141, 155, 169);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#box2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 180, 180);
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#box3 {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 180, 180);
}
#box4 {
  background: #FFF;
  float: left;
  width: 175px;
  height: 375px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(180, 180, 180);
}
#box5 {
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  height: 375px;
}
#box6 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
#leftcolumn {
  float: left;
}
#rightcolumn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout" class="Absolute-Center">

  <div id="box1">Application Title</div>
  <div id="box2">
    <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">Some text in here later</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>


  <div id="box3">

    <!-- LEFT WINDOW PANE -->
    <div id="box4">
      <ul>
        <li data-show="#1">File Information</li>
        <li data-show="#2">Comments</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- RIGHT WINDOW PANE -->
    <div id="box5"></div>

  </div>

  <div id="box6"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is just a bad way to go about laying out your page.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for improvement.

Comment: How about like this? https://jsfiddle.net/z5hf5qwf/

Comment: Yup! that will work my friend! Please post it as a solution and I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of positioning with absolute, change it to `margin: auto` with a set width, that way the height will be dependent on the elements inside and the border will adjust with the container. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z5hf5qwf/

**CSS**

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;


}
#layout {
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```